# Github Deploying Readme file instead of project file

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, package.json

I tried deploying my project but it is showing readme file instead.
It said to select the gh-pages branch but I only have master branch.
[Master branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3oBT.png)

I already edited the package.jason file by adding homepage and "redeploy", "deploy". How do I show my project instead of the readme file?